# Not able to set git ssh URL

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying set upstream url of a git repo of mine at github with SSH. But it always uses https url.
Steps I have done-

1. `git clone git@github.com:pr4bh4sh/ios-with-swift.git` and output

   `$ git clone git@github.com:pr4bh4sh/ios-with-swift.git                                                                       Cloning into 'ios-with-swift'...
   remote: Counting objects: 117, done.
   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (88/88), done.
   remote: Total 117 (delta 29), reused 103 (delta 19), pack-reused 0
   Receiving objects: 100% (117/117), 467.42 KiB | 73.00 KiB/s, done.
   Resolving deltas: 100% (29/29), done.
   Checking connectivity... done.`
2. `git remote -v` output is

   `master $ g remote -v                                                                                             origin   https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/ios-with-swift.git (fetch)
   origin  https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/ios-with-swift.git (push)`
3. `git config remote.origin.url` output

   `git@github.com:pr4bh4sh/ios-with-swift.git`

I have also tried setting it with `git remote set-url` I can see that in config it's set to ssh url but `git remote -v` show `https` url.

It happening on MacOSX el Capitan. I have also tried the steps on Ubuntu 15.10 and it works fine there.
Ubuntu has git v2.9.3 and on Mac I have tried with v2.9.3 and v2.10.0

I don't want to cache the authentication so please don't suggest that as solution.

Comment: That shouldn't happen and I can't reproduce your problem with /usr/bin/git on OS X (2.8.4 Apple Git-73). Are you sure the clone succeeded? Are you running `git remote -v` in the right directory? Do you have anything funny in `~/.gitconfig`? Could you show the actual command you used rather than `<githuburl>`?

Comment: Yes clone is succeeded as I can pull and push using username and password.

Comment: Did *that particular clone* succeed? Are you sure you didn't get "*fatal: destination path 'ios-with-swift' already exists and is not an empty directory.*"? Did you `cd` into the clone before running `git remote`? I suspect you have an existing clone using `https` and your new `ssh` clone is inside it. A `git status` would reveal it. It would be simpler to paste the actual shell commands and their output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not normal behavior. Here's what I think happened.

- `git clone https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/ios-with-swift.git`
- `cd ios-with-swift`
- `git clone git@github.com:pr4bh4sh/ios-with-swift.git`
- `git remote -v`

You cloned inside your clone. If you run `git status` you will see this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ios-with-swift/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

---

Here's an alternative.

- `git clone https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/ios-with-swift.git`
- `git clone git@github.com:pr4bh4sh/ios-with-swift.git`
- `cd ios-with-swift`
- `git remote -v`

The second clone will fail with "*fatal: destination path 'ios-with-swift' already exists and is not an empty directory*" but that may have been missed or ignored. You're left with your existing https clone.

---

If it's none of those, please show both `.git/config` and `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: Thank you FIXED IT, so I compared the ```~/.gitconfig``` on my both mac and Ubuntu machine and there was the culprit. In mac i found ```[url "https://github.com/"] insteadOf = git@github.com:``` and at ubuntu nothing else except the. ```[user] <name> <email>```. Just commented the extra thingy and boom, everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing `.git/config` directly to use the `ssh://` url? That’d be my first step.

Comment: as in `ssh://<giturl without protocal>.git`